# How to add geometries from latest version of three.js in forge-viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am trying to add customized geometry in forge-viewer, I am facing following issue:

The forge viewer I am using is `4.2.*` , which uses `THREE-R71`. (All versions of forge-viewer uses THREE-R71).

The Customized Geometry I am trying to add in forge viewer is from `THREE-R94`. It throws exception:
`THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D`

I tried to upgrade the scene as : `viewer.impl.scene=new THREE.Scene()`
(THREE-R94)

But the renderer is still from THREE-R71, so renderer cannot render the scene.
Is there any way to add geometries and objects from latest threejs in forge-viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Threejs has made breaking changes in many of its version upgrades, making them incompatible.

We have some forge articles that say otherwise, like this:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-add-newest-threejs-features-forge-viewer

It's possible to use different versions, depending heavily on which version, but almost all changes break the code compatibility.

I was unable to use different versions with the methods and objects I wanted.

If you don't want any trouble, stuck with r71 and extend the methods you need yourself.